# Quadratic expression with any matrix has quadratic expression with symmetric matrix equivalent

Tags: symmetric-matrices

Given $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ show that there exists a symmetric matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$  (which means $B^T = B$) for all A such that:
$$x^TBx=x^TAx$$

This statement totally makes sense to me when I try it with different examples but not sure how to formally prove it.

Comment: Hint: $x^T A x = x^T A^T x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A = \dfrac 12(A + A^T) + \dfrac 12(A - A^T)$.

Since $x^TAx$ is a scalar, then $x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx$

Let $B =  \dfrac 12(A + A^T)$. Then

\begin{align}
   x^TAx 
      &= \dfrac 12x^T(A + A^T)x + \dfrac 12x^T(A - A^T)x \\
      &= x^TBx + \dfrac 12x^TAx - \dfrac 12x^TA^Tx \\
      &= x^TBx + \dfrac 12x^TA^Tx - \dfrac 12x^TA^Tx \\
      &= x^TBx
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

You just have to balance the coefficients of the quadratic form given by $A$. Just take $b_{ij}=(a_{ij}+a_{ji})/2$.